# SUMIF column by comparing two date columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

Please help with this formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A3:A$900="";"";IF(DATEVALUE(History!C$3:C$900)<D3:D900;SUMIF(History!A$3:A$900;A3:A900;C$3:C$900)*SUMIF(History!A$3:A$900;A3:A900;History!B$3:$B900);"")))
```

I want to SUM `C3:C900` if the dates in `History!C3:C900` are less than the dates in `Data!D3:D900`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17C9FDyXHnFLk5z706bBI6iHjHleq21LZm4YCagsOuCY/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task, either the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) or [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) functions together with [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) will work best.

In both cases, the [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) function enables passing each pair of lookup values,  "Ticker Symbol" and "ExDate Dividend", into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function mapped to the variables **`t`** for **t**icker, and **`d`** for **d**ate.  The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function then applies its formula once for each set of values.

### QUERY Formula

The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)'s formula uses [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) **`History!B:B`** if both

- the symbol in **`History!A:A`** matches **`t`** ,   *AND*
- the date in **`History!C:C`** is prior to **`d`**

```
=MAP(A3:A; D3:D; LAMBDA(t; d; IF(t<>""; 
   QUERY(History!A:C; "select sum(B) 
     where A matches '"&t&"' AND C < date '"&TEXT(d;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
     Label sum(B) ''");
   IFERROR(1/0))))
```

[image]

### FILTER Formula

1. [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535) was used simply to avoid retyping the range **`History!A:C`**  instead assigning it the name **`h`**
2. [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) is used to return columns in **`h`** by their position
3. The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function's formula applies a [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to **`History!B:B` /  `INDEX(h;;2)`** where both

   - the ticker in **`History!A:A`** matches **`t`** ,   *AND*
   - the date in **`History!C:C`** is prior to **`d`**
4. The [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) function is applied to the filtered values.

```
=LET(h; History!A:C;
   MAP(A3:A; D3:D; LAMBDA(t; d; 
       IF(t<>""; 
          SUM(FILTER(INDEX(h;;2); INDEX(h;;1)=t; INDEX(h;;3)<d));
          IFERROR(1/0)))))
```

[image]